# How to prevent figure captions overrunning page

Tags: pdftex, captions, margins

I am having trouble with some latex formatting.  Specifically the figure caption on one of my figures is overrunning the page margins.  I wanted my image to be able to expand past them but now this may be causing an issue with my figures.  I have provided links to the .tex document and the .cls document the .tx needs to generate my thesis

[ubcthesis.cls](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1jyG2TWalzR7OgQGrxEkIoGwu2o2dC5FA4r6FAM8GFW0/edit?usp=sharing)

[main.tex](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1T2aB75JEc9i45T83Jr2I36sxisX-4bllgH5yXorgrms/edit?usp=sharing)

The code for the figure is here:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centerline{\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{introduction_figures/MemStagesV2.png}}
\caption[Stages of memory formation]
{Stages of memory formation, boundary of different stages and necessity of transcription and synaptic plasticity for each. a) Shows the approximate timeline of the various stages of memory formation.  ~\textbf{Encoding} is the initial learning which can occur in milliseconds or over a few minutes or hours.  ~\textbf{Consolidation} involves passive processes which strengthen and weaken synapses on the activated neurons.  During resting periods after encoding, offline reactivation takes place within the first few hours, and during sleep, it contributes to consolidation. After consolidating memories enter~\textbf{long-term maintenance} and become ~\textbf{remote memory}. b)  Synaptic plasticity and transcription have been established to be necessary in different brain regions at different times for each process.  Synaptic blockade during encoding prevents encoding but not consolidation, blockage in hippocampus during sleep prevents later retrieval possibly through inhibition of offline replay during sleep.  Inhibiting transcription at any point during consolidation will prevent altered memory retrieval.  Transcription is hypothesized by the NGS engram literature to be required for long term maintenance for retrieval at remote time points weeks and months later.}
\label{fig:stageofmemoryformationandmaintenance}
\end{figure}
```

And the resulting issue is this...

[image]

As you can see the caption is running over the apge margin and close to the edge of the page, if it runs over it instead of being printed on the next page it simply gets cut off by the page.  Would also be nice to know how to expand my page margins it's not clear to me how to do that in this document.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  I think this would likely fit if placement were limited to a page by itself (option `[p]`).  Also, if reasonable, perhaps you could provide only a short phrase for the formal caption, and include the remainder of the information still within the figure, but as additional text, where the text could be the full textwidth,  If nothing else is on the page, it should be clear that the text belongs to the figure.

Comment: That's a pretty long caption. At some point, one should move that text into the document?

Comment: Suffice it to say, this is not normal behavior.  Since the caption is (usually) inside the float, the float should  go to the next page instead.  Now if ubcthesis is using the float package or its own custom setup, all bets are off.

Comment: If you are using `[H]` type figures, you should probably use `\raggedbottom` to remove the penalty for leaving big ugly gaps in your document.

Comment: I didn't create the document, the links to the overleaf documents copy pasted into google docs have been provided.  I was hoping someone could tell me whether a package is screwing up the margins.  Also not fully sure what parameter is setting them in the first place.